# trying to use bootstrap 3 for nested columns but their being hidden

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzS1Q.png)I'm trying to have an information panel with three different columns using bootstrap 3. I've nested the columns properly, I think, but the panels are hidden beneath the main row and I can't find a way to reveal it.

[it's showing that the container is there, but you can't see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzS1Q.png)

```
<div class="row creative_line">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2 class="text-center">Smart &amp; Creative<br><p>This is why you will use it</p></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 multi">
          <div class="img-circle">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 ui">
          <div class="img-circle">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 design">
          <div class="img-circle">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is my current css

```
.creative_line {
  background: yellow;
  min-height: 300px;
  color: $primary-color;
  font-family: $font-stack;
}

.creative_line p {
  color: $primary-color;
  font-family: $font-stack2;
  font-size: 35%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
}


.img-circle {
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
  clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
    background: red;
}

.multi,
.ui,
.design {
  min-height: 300px;
  color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Please place your code in this post rather than attaching an image with it.

Comment: sorry still figuring things out

Comment: your code works fine [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bzd5pxwm/)

Comment: gotchya Koschtik, the issue is that the shapes I'm trying to put into the container is hidden

Comment: right below my html @makshh

Comment: Why do you use clip-path? It is not clear what you want to do.

Comment: sorry about that dippas, really appreciate it!!